# Best java web development tools

Tags: java, jsf

I am currently developing jsf web applications using netbeans and tomcat .but deployment process taking lots of time and this decreasing productivity a lot,and waiting to see effect of changes turning pain. But writing  .net with its embedded web server is painless,i know jsf has dependency injection ,which asp.net not has.But there must be more productive platforms ,What is the best tools(ide,server,plug-ins ...) for increasing throughput of a java web developer.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend JSF to anyone.

Comment: have you tried JSF with Netbeans and GlassFish. Its is very integrated environment, where your changes will become visible in an instant. (With no need to do manual deply or even compile).

Comment: @duffymo, so what would you recommend? Personally, I wouldn't make a recommendation because I don't know much about web development. :)

Comment: @duffymo: the problems described by OP are not related to JSF. The OP would still have the same slow deployment problem when using other frameworks like Spring, Struts, Wicket, etc on exactly the same development environment.

Comment: @ayengin: Tomcat is the culprit here. It's a terrible hotdeployer. Actually, it basically just redeploys the **entire** webapp on every change. Get yourself Glassfish. Changes in views and beans are instantly reflected in Glassfish's memory.

Comment: Jrebel is a perfect tool for this problem.